# Create new TAR file in current directory to a new directory without using "mv" (shell script)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tar

I'm currently setting up a backupmanager to automatically archive directories from webserver. I'm searching for an answer how to create a new TAR file of the current directory to a new (different) directory without using `mv` after the archiving process. See my command:

```
dcreate=$(date +%Y_%d_%m) tar -cvpzf backup_$dcreate.tar.gz plugins/folder_to_archive/
```

This command works fine, but i'm struggeling now on how to move it to a new directory directly after the archiv process is terminated, for example:

`plugins/plugin_name/` to `plugins/backups/`

Any help appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Why the "without using `mv`" constraint? What do you actually intend to accomplish or achieve by that?

Comment: (...am I correct in understanding, by the way, that your goal is not to have the partially-created archive visible while it's being actively written?)

Comment: (as an aside, `tar` isn't a standardized command at all -- the POSIX-standardized command to use to create `tar`-format archives is [`pax`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pax.html) -- so it's hard to say what any given operating system's `tar` command actually will or won't do; since you're tagged Linux, we can *probably* assume GNU, but milage or extensions may vary).

Comment: I thought it could be accomplished with passing my desired task as an argument to TAR. Of course i can mv the output to an new directory, but is this best practice?

Comment: You can certainly have `tar` create the file in a directory of your choice, but if you want it to appear there as an atomic operation, then a separate `mv` is in fact appropriate.

Comment: By the way, putting the `dcreate` assignment on the same line as the `tar` command with no intervening separator (ie. `;`) makes its value available *as an environment variable* during `tar`'s execution, but **doesn't** substitute that value for uses of `$decreate` on `tar`'s command line.

Comment: ...so, part of the question here: Do you just care about *where* the archive is created (in which case the answer by Dietmar suffices), or do you want it to be created there whole and complete, not existing at all in the destination directory until after the archive operation has reported success?

Comment: (BTW, you can only guarantee atomicity if the temporary location is on the same filename as the destination -- for that reason, it's common practice for incomplete temporary files to be created *in the destination directory* with a different name, and renamed to the final name when finished; indeed, some filesystems -- NFS and AFS particularly come to mind -- only guarantee atomicity of renames at all when both source and destination are in the same directory).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks a lot for your reply on my issue. I have implemented the logic from above, especially intervening separtors and got a full success. I guess `mv` just renamed the file, so had to extend $dcreate variable with a timestamp to ensure the possibility of a file move.
Best regards

Comment: If you want to be 100% certain of uniqueness, this is what `mktemp` does -- there's a category of security vulnerabilities called "symlink attacks", where if a less-privileged process and a more-privileged process both have write access to the same directory and the less-privileged process can predict a filename that will be used by the more-privileged process, it can create a symlink there pointing at something it wants to have deleted or overwritten but doesn't have access to itself. `mktemp` uses the `O_EXCL` flag in conjunction w/ `O_CREAT` to avoid this.

Comment: ...so, with a time-based temporary file, an attacker just needs to make sure a symlink exists for every possible time within the range in which it predicts the more-privileged script to be run.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Thanks for mentioning to be aware of security vulnerabilites. It took me a while to understand how the file set permission takes effect with `mktemp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-f` option of tar is the destination file for the archive; it can be anywhere you want, i.e., you can change

`-cvpzf "backup_$dcreate.tar.gz"`

to

`-cvpzf "plugins/backups/backup_$dcreate.tar.gz"`

if you want your new archive to be created in `plugins/backups/`

Comment: This is missing quotes. `"backup_$dcreate.tar.gz"` or `backup_"$decreate".tar.gz` would be more correct: As it is, if `dcreate` contained whitespace, this would be split into multiple distinct arguments rather than passed as a single filename. (This could even happen with the current value if `IFS` contained `_`, or another character present in the dates).

Comment: You're right, but your comment would make more sense on the original question, where I just took this from. As you can also see there, `$dcreate` will actually not contain whitespace.
But I edited my post nevertheless to include the quotes.

Comment: A question is expected to reflect places where the OP has room for improvement -- if they knew everything already, they wouldn't be asking. An answer is expected to show the right way to do things, and to be something that not just the OP but anyone with a similar problem can refer to.

Comment: @Dietmar: Thanks a lot for your answer. Your proposed solution from above is also working, but in fact my question wasn't very clear. Anyway thanks for you help. Appreciate a lot. Regards.

Comment: @Allan please accept the answer if it answered your question